# how to convert results of a for loop to a list?

Tags: r

I have several files in a directory. I can read them like this:

```
files <- list.files("C:\\New folder", "*.bin",full.names=TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
conne <- file(files[i], "rb")
file  <- readBin(conne, double(), size=4,  n=300*700, signed=TRUE)
file2 <- matrix(data=file,ncol=700,nrow=300)
                           }
```

I wonder how can I put all the matrices (file2) as a list?
For instance:

```
 m1<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))
 m2<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))
```

I put them in a list as:

```
ml <- list(m1, m2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to akrun's answer, you could also just put them in a list to begin with by taking advantage of the `lapply` function. Modifying your code just slightly, it would look like this:

```
files <- list.files("C:\\New folder", "*.bin",full.names=TRUE)

dat <- lapply(1:length(files), function(i) {
  conne <- file(files[i], "rb")
  file  <- readBin(conne, double(), size=4,  n=300*700, signed=TRUE)
  file2 <- matrix(data=file,ncol=700,nrow=300)
  close(conne) # as indicated in the comments below
  return(file2)
})
```

`dat` is now a list of all of your matrices. `lapply` acts as a loop, much like `for`, and will pass each iteration of its first argument, here `1:length(files)`, to the function as a parameter. The returned value it gets from the function will be passed to the list called `dat` as its own element.

Comment: Not exactly what `list` does, but the results should be the same as `list(m1, m2, ...)`. Given that you're new to R, I would highly recommend running the different codes and seeing the results as it's a very informative exercise.

Comment: You may want to add `close(conne)` before the `return` statement

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the OP created objects 'm1', 'm2' etc in the global envrironment, we can use `mget` to get the values of the object in a `list` by specifying the `pattern` argument in the `ls` as 'm' followed by numbers (`\\d+`).

```
mget(ls(pattern='m\\d+'))
```

---

If the question is to `split` up a large matrix into chunks

```
 n <- 4
 lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(m)), 
    as.numeric(gl(nrow(m), n, nrow(m)))),  function(i) m[i,])
```